# Trying to create topnav of equal width for my website, includes buttons and can't seem to figure out how to make them too the same width as links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried including the dropbtn to the width attribute but can't seem to make it work and was just looking for advice, so I want the two buttons named "Products" and "Services" to both be equal in width to that of the links. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JAST.png)

HTML

```
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
              <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Products</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/product.html">ALL PRODUCTS</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Services</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/services.html">All Services</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
              <a href="/about.html">About</a>
              <a href="#">Customer Login</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

</script>
```

CSS

```
.topnav {
  width: 84%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #706f6f;
  margin: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 14%;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav .dropbtn {
    width: 14%;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #706f6f;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2d2e83;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: .5s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #2d2e83;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content{
      display: none;
    }
}
```

So I want the all parts of the nav bar to be equal in width.

Comment: You should be giving `.dropdown` the same width as its link siblings, not the button _within_ it. Right now, you made your buttons have 14% width _of the dropdown width_.

Comment: (And instead of still trying to wrestle floats, you should really rather go look into flexbox.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you must change some html structure for the set to put all fields in the center and all fields in the same size as per your requirement with mobile design, so try the below code and change some code structure to fulfill your requirement.

```css
    .topnav {
        width: 84%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #706f6f;
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .topnav>div {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnav .dropbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: #706f6f;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .topnav a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #2d2e83;
        color: #ffffff;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #2d2e83;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .topnav .link:not(:first-child),
        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            display: none;
        }

        .topnav .link.icon,
        .topnav .link .icon {
            float: right;
            display: block;
        }

        .topnav.responsive {
            position: relative;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .topnav.responsive>div {
            flex: 0 0 100%;
        }

        .topnav a {
            text-align: left;
            width: auto;
        }

        .topnav.responsive .icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .topnav.responsive .link {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
            float: none;
        }

        .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
            position: relative;
        }

        .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div class="link">
            <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Products</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/product.html">ALL PRODUCTS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Services</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/services.html">All Services</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="/about.html">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="#">Customer Login</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
    </script>
```